# Xamarin ListView -> An unhandled exception occured

Tags: listview, xamarin

Ошибка возникает в любом проекте, хоть в стартовом, если на него добавить ListView и именно при подключении адаптера к листу. При этом, если адаптер не подключать, лист будет выводиться, но пустым. Эмулятор Genymotion, последней версии.

```
[Activity(Label = "AddressesActivity")]
public class AddressesActivity : Activity
{
List streetList, houseList, flatList;
string[] hydromerCount, licNumber;

    ListView listViewAddresses;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.AddressesList);

        listViewAddresses = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listViewAddresses);

        List<string> l = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" }.ToList();

        ArrayAdapter streetAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(
            this,
            Resource.Layout.AddressesList,
            l
        );

        listViewAddresses.Adapter = streetAdapter; //тут возникает ошибка
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>         
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"             
  android:orientation="vertical"             
  android:layout_width="match_parent"             
  android:layout_height="match_parent">             
 <ListView                 
   android:minWidth="25px"                 
   android:minHeight="25px"                 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"                 
   android:layout_height="match_parent"                 
   android:id="@+id/listViewAddresses" />         
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Если "тут" ошибка, значит listViewAddresses  null - т.е. не отработала `FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listViewAddresses);` смотрите дебагером почему. По вопросу не понятно почему посредством ID вы ищите listViewAddresses и должен ли он в этом списке быть. "Адрес" (listViewAddresses) может как соответствовать id так и нет. В вашем случае почему-то нет.

Comment: А что такое параметр равный 1 при создании адаптера? Похоже вы используете перегрузку где должно быть textViewResourceId

Comment: @nick_n_a, тогда бы приложение не запускалось с пустым листом тоже, а `FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listViewAddresses);` возвращает элемент правильно.
@vitidev, это не 1 - это L из `List<string> l = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" }.ToList();`

Comment: Я unhandled c null-ошибкой перепутал (похожи), покажите больше или весь дамп ошибки.

Comment: @nick_n_a, в том то и дело что дампа нет, ну или он пишется где-то в логи VS и его надо от туда доставать.